# GPU versions of OpenCV algorithms slower than CPU versions on my machine?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu

While trying to speed up a simple algorithm using the GPU with OpenCV, I noticed that on my machine (Ubuntu 12.10, NVidia 9800GT, Cuda 4.2.9, g++ 4.7.2) the GPU Version is actually slower than the CPU version. I tested with the following code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    Mat img1(512, 512, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f));
    Mat img2(128, 128, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f));
    Mat img3(128, 128, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f));

    auto startCPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double resultCPU(0.0);
    cout << "CPU ... " << flush;
    for (int y(0); y < img2.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x(0); x < img2.cols; ++x)
        {
            Mat roi(img1(Rect(x, y, img2.cols, img2.rows)));
            Mat diff;
            absdiff(roi, img2, diff);
            Mat diffMult(diff.mul(img3));
            Scalar diffSum(sum(diff));
            double diffVal(diffSum[0] + diffSum[1] + diffSum[2]);
            resultCPU += diffVal;
        }
    }
    auto endCPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedCPU = endCPU - startCPU;
    cout << "done. " << resultCPU << " - ticks: " << elapsedCPU.count() << endl;

    gpu::GpuMat img1GPU(img1);
    gpu::GpuMat img2GPU(img2);
    gpu::GpuMat img3GPU(img3);
    gpu::GpuMat diffGPU;
    gpu::GpuMat diffMultGPU;
    gpu::GpuMat sumBuf;

    double resultGPU(0.0);
    auto startGPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "GPU ... " << flush;
    for (int y(0); y < img2GPU.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x(0); x < img2GPU.cols; ++x)
        {
            gpu::GpuMat roiGPU(img1GPU, Rect(x, y, img2GPU.cols, img2GPU.rows));
            gpu::absdiff(roiGPU, img2GPU, diffGPU);
            gpu::multiply(diffGPU, img3GPU, diffMultGPU);
            Scalar diffSum(gpu::sum(diffMultGPU, sumBuf));
            double diffVal(diffSum[0] + diffSum[1] + diffSum[2]);
            resultGPU += diffVal;
        }
    }
    auto endGPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedGPU = endGPU - startGPU;
    cout << "done. " << resultGPU << " - ticks: " << elapsedGPU.count() << endl;
}
```

My result is as follows:

```
CPU ... done. 8.05306e+07 - ticks: 4028470
GPU ... done. 3.22122e+07 - ticks: 5459935
```

If this helps: My profiler (System Profiler 1.1.8) tells me that most of the time is spend in `cudaDeviceSynchronize`.

Am I doing wrong something fundamental with the way I use the OpenCV GPU functions or is my GPU just slow?

Comment: I'm not complete sure how opencv acts if you're calling `Scalar diffSum(gpu::sum(diffMultGPU, sumBuf));` I think it makes only a memcpy from the scalar element. So you would have a tiny copy operation from the gpu to the host for every single image element. That would cost a lot of time.

Comment: maybe you can write a mini kernel instead of this line, that keeps the `diffval` and `resultGPU` on the gpu while the two for-loops and only at the end you'll add a single memcpy from cuda to the host with the final result.

Comment: Allocating mem space for both `Mat` and `GpuMat` objects before the nested for loops may increase the CPU & GPU performance.

Comment: How is the GPU slower? 3.22 is less than 8.05

Comment: @KansaiRobot The 3.22 and the 8.05 are not durations, those are checksums. The GPU was slower because it took 5459935 (time) ticks, but the CPU only took 4028470 ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of hubs and Eric I was able to change my test in a way that the GPU version actually became faster than the CPU version. The mistake leading to the different checksums of both versions is now also eliminated. ;-)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    Mat img1(512, 512, CV_32FC3, Scalar(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f));
    Mat img2(128, 128, CV_32FC3, Scalar(4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f));
    Mat img3(128, 128, CV_32FC3, Scalar(7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f));
    Mat resultCPU(img2.rows, img2.cols, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    auto startCPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "CPU ... " << flush;
    for (int y(0); y < img1.rows - img2.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x(0); x < img1.cols - img2.cols; ++x)
        {
            Mat roi(img1(Rect(x, y, img2.cols, img2.rows)));
            Mat diff;
            absdiff(roi, img2, diff);
            Mat diffMult(diff.mul(img3));
            resultCPU += diffMult;
        }
    }
    auto endCPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedCPU = endCPU - startCPU;
    Scalar meanCPU(mean(resultCPU));
    cout << "done. " << meanCPU << " - ticks: " << elapsedCPU.count() << endl;

    gpu::GpuMat img1GPU(img1);
    gpu::GpuMat img2GPU(img2);
    gpu::GpuMat img3GPU(img3);
    gpu::GpuMat diffGPU(img2.rows, img2.cols, CV_32FC3);
    gpu::GpuMat diffMultGPU(img2.rows, img2.cols, CV_32FC3);
    gpu::GpuMat resultGPU(img2.rows, img2.cols, CV_32FC3, Scalar(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    auto startGPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "GPU ... " << flush;
    for (int y(0); y < img1GPU.rows - img2GPU.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x(0); x < img1GPU.cols - img2GPU.cols; ++x)
        {
            gpu::GpuMat roiGPU(img1GPU, Rect(x, y, img2GPU.cols, img2GPU.rows));
            gpu::absdiff(roiGPU, img2GPU, diffGPU);
            gpu::multiply(diffGPU, img3GPU, diffMultGPU);
            gpu::add(resultGPU, diffMultGPU, resultGPU);
        }
    }
    auto endGPU = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto elapsedGPU = endGPU - startGPU;
    Mat downloadedResultGPU(resultGPU);
    Scalar meanGPU(mean(downloadedResultGPU));
    cout << "done. " << meanGPU << " - ticks: " << elapsedGPU.count() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
CPU ... done. [3.09658e+06, 3.53894e+06, 3.98131e+06, 0] - ticks: 34021332
GPU ... done. [3.09658e+06, 3.53894e+06, 3.98131e+06, 0] - ticks: 20609880
```

That is not the speedup I expected, but probably my GPU is just not the best for this stuff. Thanks guys.

Comment: I wouldn't want to exclude CPU-GPU data transfer latency when comparing performance. That transfer time is an important practical consideration in deciding whether to use the GPU or not, regardless of whether the algorithm performs better once the data is on the card. Often, work on small matrices is faster on the CPU, and the GPU only pays off for work beyond a given size where the latency is overshadowed by the performance benefits.

Comment: I don't understand why and into what you changed your method of evaluating performance. A Mat?? (resultCPU)

Comment: @KansaiRobot `resultCPU` and `resultGPU` are not values to measure the performance/durations. Those are checksums, that only exist to make sure both methods (CPU and GPU) give the same result. The duration measurements are in `elapsedCPU` and `elapsedGPU`, and printed to stdout as "ticks".