# OpenCV 3.4 C++ Cuda acceleration takes more time than CPU

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I am testing OpenCV GPU acceleration with CUDA but GPU is slower than CPU. Is it only about median filter or am I doing something wrong in my code? And Why is pure process time on GPU higher than CPU?

Output:

```
Device 0:  "GeForce GT 330M"  1023Mb, sm_12 (not Fermi), 
48 cores, Driver/Runtime ver.6.50/6.50
Size of the Image: 512 x 512
GPU Time Includes up&download Times: 8531/100 = 85ms
GPU Time Includes only 'apply': 8307/100 = 83ms
CPU Time: 1855/100 = 18ms
```

Code:

```
void CPUvsGPU()
{
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    Mat cSrc;
    Mat cGray;
    cuda::GpuMat gGray;
    cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cuda::getDevice());
    cSrc = imread("baboon.jpg");
    cout << "Size of the Image: " << cSrc.size << endl;

    cvtColor(cSrc, cGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    gGray.upload(cGray);

    Mat cOut(cGray.size(), CV_8U);
    cuda::GpuMat gOut(gGray.size(), CV_8U);

    Ptr <cuda::Filter> mf;
    mf = cuda::createMedianFilter(CV_8UC1,9);

    mf->apply(gGray, gOut);//don't measure first operation's time on GPU

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i<100 ; i++)
    {
        gGray.upload(cGray);
        mf->apply(gGray, gOut);
        gOut.download(cOut);
    }
    cout << "GPU Time Includes up&download Times: " << timer.elapsed() << "/100 = " << timer.elapsed()/100 <<"ms" << endl;

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i<100 ; i++)
        mf->apply(gGray, gOut);
    cout << "GPU Time Includes only 'apply': " << timer.elapsed() << "/100 = " << timer.elapsed()/100 <<"ms" << endl;

    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i<100 ; i++)
        medianBlur(cGray,cOut,9);
    cout << "CPU Time: " << timer.elapsed() << "/100 = " << timer.elapsed()/100 <<"ms" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are running on what is literally one of the smallest and slowest CUDA GPUs ever made. Perhaps a better question is why you would expect the GPU be faster?

Comment: @talonmies Everything is clear now :) What is the main criteria of the fast CUDA GPU?  Number of CUDA cores, frame buffer , clock speed or anything else?

Comment: yes cuda cores is a factor but it's relative to clock speed as well as memory speed, so yes 48 cuda cores is not that much ( I have 1050 ti with 768 cuda cores and it's not the best on the market)

Comment: median filter should not be so great on gpu, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), your GPU is listed in legacy GPUs.

Also try to look in [GPU versions of OpenCV algorithms slower than CPU versions on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551017/gpu-versions-of-opencv-algorithms-slower-than-cpu-versions-on-my-machine?rq=1) and in [Why Opencv GPU code is slower than CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074281/why-opencv-gpu-code-is-slower-than-cpu?rq=1) for other problems to take into consideration when doing comparison. The acceleration you get isn't same for all functions. Some get small enhancement and some a very remarkable speed.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect.  The GPU is listed [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus) and supports CUDA, albeit only through CUDA 6.5.  However since OP's posting clearly indicates use of CUDA 6.5, I don't see any evidence to support your statement.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for your comment. I have removed the wrong statement. I haven't looked at legacy list.

Comment: The second link basically deals with the initialization time problem for GPUs but OpenCV GPU code sometimes is slower despite that initialization time